# Windows 10 Cortana not showing documents from partition d: (c: works, d: is indexed...)

Tags: windows-10, cortana, document-scanning

I've installed win 10 on my grandpa's computer, who is blind and so he really needs the "cortana quick document search and open feature" which means typing 2-3 characters of document FILENAME and open it with enter. 
This works really well on documents which are on partition C: but not with documents on partition D:

Of course I've added folders and even the whole drive d: to the index settings and finished the index process several times, but it is not working on the first quick view - only bing search phrases are shown. (when I click on "Meine Dokumente" (my documents in english version?), but this way is too uncomfortable for my grandpa...)
I've also checked the settings in windows explorer (allow indexing from this drive...) but still it does not work. And also checked the settings for the .extension, but I do not have a screenshot of it.

Can please anybody help me? And to clarify: I'm not talking about in file text scanning, just the filename of .doc(s) and .xls

I've attached some screenshots to show the exact problem (we are from Austria, so sorry for german windows):

its working on "my documents" but not in quickview and some settings: 
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdYvX.jpg